# Huawei Y330-U11 bootloop

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, boot-loop

My device, Huawei Y330-U11, is stuck on a bootloop.

Recovery isn't working. The only possible mode is "Fastboot & Rescue" mode, which needs the phone to be connected to the PC. But, the phone is not being detected.

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading a stock y330-u11 firmware from Susutun then extract the zip. Read fully the instruction given. Once you've got the SP flash tool, check the scatter file and the uboot. Choose Recovery and boot. Then hit download. Turn of the phone and pull out battery. Reinstall the battery but don't power on. Connect the usb while holding vol up/down. The progress bar should start.